# How to put an <a> tag around the whole cell in angular table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've this code currently to add the `<a>` tag in a cell in an angular table.

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="myColumn">
      <th *matHeaderCellDef class="table-column" mat-header-cell>
        My Column
      </th>
      <td *matCellDef="let element" class="table-row" mat-cell>
        <a [routerLink]="['./details', element.id]" [state]="{ data: element }">
          {{ element.someProperty }}
        </a>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

This only wraps the `{{ element.someProperty }}` in the  element and thus clicking anywhere in the cell (red part in my attached picutre) doesn't work

[image]

My question is how do i wrap the whole cell?

Comment: The only allowed parent for `td` and `th` elements is a `tr` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
td {
  padding: 0;
}

td a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I ended using `padding: 0 !important;` for the <td> and `padding: 16px 4px 16px 24px;
  display: block;` for any future readers as this stretched the whole cell for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

don't use an `<a>` tag at all with angular. instead do this:

```
  <td [routerLink]="['./details', element.id]" [state]="{ data: element }" *matCellDef="let element" class="table-row" mat-cell>
      {{ element.someProperty }}
  </td>
```

Comment: This has no effect whatsoever. Am i missing anything?

Comment: huh? with this code it will route no matter where you click in the cell. wasn't that the goal?

Comment: the point is, add the router to the `<td>` tag, not the `<a>` tag

Comment: It does the routing but it does not have the same functionality as the <a> tag as with the <a> tag i can hold ctrl pressed and it will open in a new tab and i can click on the cell with the right moust click and say open in a new tab. With this however, it can not